# Working over networks

Tags: networking

I am using a aix box over a network. 
I am using putty to work on the box. The problem is its too slow,But we do have a high speed network.

Is there any terminal program other than putty that can help me work comfortably..by doing some buffering or other mechanism by which i wont feel like i m working on a dialup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY is perfectly fast - I've never had any problems with it.

Have you established where the bottleneck is?  What's the exact setup of the network between your client and the server?  Is perhaps the AIX server too heavily loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem depending on where I am. Lately, at home, I'm stuck with my horribly slow back up connection while my primary ISP goes through 'growing pains'

Its been a while since I have used putty, does it have an option for gzip compression? If not, I recommend using the official OpenSSH client (but it can be painful to install on Windows).

I typically use ssh -C (compression) user@host, the speed up is almost 30%. I feel your pain, it sucks when typing and every character takes ~3 seconds to appear.